# Face detection using local binary pattern

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, histogram, face-detection

As you know, LBP is a strong feature for face detection. Usually, SVM or other similar classifier is used for classification purpose for this feature.
But in some paper, Adaptive Boosting methods like AdaBoost are used. Using AdaBoost with haar-like feature is clear, because each weak classifier is a haar-like feature with a [x,y,w,h] which we calculate a [threshold, polarity] for it.
But in case of LBP, i could not understand what structure should be used?
I read [this paper](http://s3.picofile.com/file/7467070749/Robust_face_detection_using_local_gradient_patterns_and_evidence_accumulatin.rar.html), it applied LBP (in fact LGP) to each pixel of training images and calculated a histogram for each feature.
but how can we using AdaBoost and a bunch of histograms?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Haarcascade with LBP features in Opencv. You can use it or see the code to understand how it is done for LBP features.